# Laravel Stripe Subscriptions, Charges and Customers Advanced Query

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

How do I get Charges that have Customers that don't have any Subscriptions?

Maybe something like this:

```
$charges = Charge::all([
    'customers' => Customer::all([
        'subscriptions' => false
    ])
]);
```

Is there a fluent way to do this?

Comment: Not with Cashier, no. You'd have to use the the SDK for your payment provider.

Comment: Can you site an example?

Comment: An example of what?

Comment: Something like
$charge = Charge::retrieve('some_id')->where('customers.subscriptions', false);

Comment: You want me to site an example of something you can't do?

Comment: Yes, please. I'm really new to laravel stripe.

Comment: I cannot give you an example of something which is impossible.